# Query Button to check if Data exist in Mysql and redirect if exist

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Is it possible to make an query Button to check the MySql Database if an info exist without reloading the Page?

I have an Bitcoin Payment page and after 1 confirmation my script add automaticly the Bitcoin address and the payment info like status, transaction hash to my Database...

Now i want make an Button on my Payment Page to check the Payment (If the Deposit Bitcoin Address exist in the MySQL DB.) without reloading the page (Because if the site reload, an new BTC address generated.) If BTC Deposit Address exist in DB the User redirect to an other page after click the Button. If the address dont exist, do nothing.

Works this with query?

**Generated BTC Address in php:**

```
$address = $respond["input_address"];
```

Now i want check `$address` if is exist in my MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE `input_address`
```

Theres any Example? Sorry for the maybe stupid Question, i am an php beginner:)

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to create a page giving you that information back and use an ajax call to call that page. It should be easily doable

Comment: Yes thanks i know it but i dont have any idea how i do this..

Comment: You don't know how to do what? Create a PHP page? Use ajax to call that page? If that's so, I suggest you go read basic ajax call examples ..

Comment: sorry, yes the ajax call

Comment: Maybe if you post your full code I could help :)

Comment: What code you need? i dont have wrote any ajax button code otherwise i dont aks here;) i want check the $address in my DB where FROM `payments` WHERE `input_address`.